# How to right align span text in a td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to figure out how to right align the span text

**html**

```
<div class="table-css">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Text aligned left in row. <span>Text aligned right in row.</span></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.table-css table { width: 600px; }
.table-css td a { display: block; }
.table-css td a:hover { background-color: #333; }
.table-css td span { display: inline; text-align: right; }
```

Result should be like this:

```
Text aligned left in row.                         Text aligned right in row.
```

Comment: FYI: `<span>`s are by default inline!

Comment: isn't it better to add another td to wrap the span and you can control it better, that is the point of table design!

Comment: @OQJordan I can't use a second TD because then I can't get the full row to show a background color when I hover over a link.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to `float` the content:

```
table-css td span {
    float: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vauu7/).

The problem with your approach is that an element that is `display: inline` will only occupy the width required for its content; which means that while it may align the text to the right it won't be visibly moved since the element is only as wide as its content.

Answer (score 2):

[`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) is generic inline container by default you can use `float` instead to align it right.

```
.table-css td span { float:right; }
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JA8sE/)

Comment: @Markaway Even in the Demo linked above?

Comment: I have .table-css td a { display: block; } and .table-css td a:hover { background-color: #333; }

Comment: Then you need to post a more accurate representative demo.